# Multiple entry/exit of Fiji without a visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, itineraries, repeat-visits, fiji

I have citizenship of a country which grants me visa-free access to Fiji as a tourist (for 4 months as I understand from the Fiji immigration website)

I am currently traveling in the South Pacific and would like to do an itinerary where I use Fiji as a base to explore the less visited islands nearby, something like this:

Fiji (1 month)
Tonga (2 weeks)
Fiji (few days to a week)
Wallis and Futuna (1 week)
Fiji (few days)
Samoa (1 month)
Fiji (few days or layover)
Vanuatu and continue on to Melanesia.

Would Fiji immigration be okay with this? I plan to buy the onward ticket to Vanuatu before arriving in Fiji and most likely will have purchased all international flights before arriving in Fiji.

Would I fill out the landing card with my first date of departure from Fiji?

Answer (score 2):

I did exactly that last summer (3 stops in Fiji). You need to treat each entry as an individual visit, so you fill the landing card out each time. They will most likely ask your hotel address in Fiji and possibly your flights out.